# Java unit test: How to know its running on SemaphoreCI?

Tags: java, junit, semaphore-ci

How is it possible to possible skip some of the tests on SemaphoreCI? 
In other words, is it possible to know when we are running a specific test on Semaphore?

Comment: Most CI's do something in addition to just launching the test - typically an environment variable you can test for presence or a given value.  I would, however, suggest that you rework your test setup so you don't have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SemaphoreCI sets the `CI` environment variable to `true`.

For a complete list of SemaphoreCI's environment variables see [Available Environment Variables](https://semaphoreci.com/docs/available-environment-variables.html)

You could use this in your testing code or in your semaphore job's configuration commands to enable or disable specific maven profiles for example.